# Parse a String to obtain id numbers

Tags: java, string

My input `String` is as below,

`{"string name"=hi;"id"=44401234;"string name"=hey;"id"=87695432.....}`

I want only the ids as output like, `{44401234 87695432}`

```
        for(int i=0;i<input.length();i++)
          {
               int index=input.indexOf("id");
               hh=input.substring(index+4,index+12);
               System.out.println(hh);
          }
```

Comment: can u improve the code

Comment: Splitting the `String` first with `;` and then with `=`, should help you do that easily.

Comment: actually the string i have put up is simpler the actual string is much complex and has all kinds of special charatcers in it

Comment: i only wanted to increment my string so that it gives new id values,it instead prints the same id everytime

Comment: This is because you are using `indexOf("id")`, this will always give you the first index of `id`.

Comment: @user2755930: Then provide a more realistic sample and your expected output.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code uses Regex to get the value associated with id

try

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

      public class Test {
            public static void main(String[] args) {
                String input = "{\"string name\"=hi;\"id\"=44401234;\"string name\"=hey;\"id\"=87695432.....}";
                Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\"id\"=[0-9]{8}");
                Matcher m = pattern.matcher(input);
                while (m.find()) {
                    String str = m.group();
                    str = str.replace("\"id\"=", "");
                    System.out.println(str);
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: what lib do i need to import for pattern and matcher

Comment: updated the code, No external  lib required

Comment: Can his names have numbers in them?

Comment: yes, The regex will match only the string that strats with "id"= and followed by 8 digit number

Comment: my code terminates without printing any output

Comment: the input string considered spans over 2 pages to parse can that be the reason?